# How has your experience been with US based www.onlinevisas.com?

Tags: usa, greencard, online-resources

The onlinevisas.com claims to have software that will make tremendous applications and a high chance of success. I want to know if someone has encountered this company. I didn't find anything about them on google or other places. Any experience shared will be good. The company is also called onlinevisas.com

Comment: If it sounds too good to be true it probably is.

Comment: @littleadv You mean it isn't. Right?

Comment: Too good to be true? It is :)

Comment: Can’t see how software, no matter how brilliantly designed, can make a difference to the outcome of an application. The software doesn’t change the facts of an applicant's circumstances, the usual ‘RIRO’ theory still applies

Comment: @Traveller What is the RIRO theory?

Comment: @PHcoDer ‘Rubbish in, rubbish out’ - in this instance meaning if the applicant’s circumstances don’t warrant a visa, the outcome will be a refusal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't intend to defame anyone. I am just sharing my experience and suspicion. I reached out to them for an assessment of my profile. The attorney gave strongly positive feedback; they also tried to convince me not to try to convince my company to get an EB-1B. Instead, they insisted on getting an EB-1A done with them.

1. My profile was good but not as good as the attorney was reacting. This made me suspicious.
2. They moved things quickly, sent me an ~$12K invoice, and asked me to pay quickly so they could start the process. The market rate for the same was $4-6K.
3. As you mentioned, they said they would use some miraculous software to prepare the petition. However, they didn't provide anything when I asked for a demo of the S/W or some stats for demonstrating its success.
4. They wanted everything to be paid upfront. I proposed to go via a retainer (like everyone else in the market does) and that I pay the fee once the application is approved (I did one thing differently here, others in the market ask for 50% advance and 50% after acceptance. I wanted to pay 100% after the approval). They insisted on 100% advance payment and didn't even offer the halfway thing. This made me suspicious about their claim of making a successful application for me. I think they were just trying to fetch money.

I never did business with them, so I cannot guarantee anything. I was suspicious enough not to continue with them.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your elaborate experience @Chor Sipahi.